# How to change origin in xCode 6.3.1?

Tags: ios, xcode, anchor

I want to change the height of the UILable but it shrinks to up instead of down, I think this related to UILable origin.
I used to change the origin of any UILable,UIView... etc from the size inspector as in the image below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hlx6u.png

But now, in xCode 6.3.1 I can not find this dots grid !
When I try to change the Anchor point programmatically, it changes the position of the UILable !

Any solution ?!
Thanks in advance,

Comment: Anchor point is never related to size. Anchor point related only to position. `UIView` actually have no `anchorPoint` (like `CALayer`). Your problem sees like is not related to this. Post your code.

Comment: Are you using any kind of constraints?  That's probably what you need

Comment: @SergeyKuryanov  There is no code, Im trying to change the height of uilabel from the size inspector and it shrinks towards up not down, so the same thing will happen when I change it through code.

Thanks for comments,

Comment: @milesper no constraints, I disabled the auto layout and remove all constraints

Comment: @SergeyKuryanov I want it to shrinks towards down, as Im using it as a Bar on Bar Chart

Comment: Now for such purposes you need to use auto layout or calculate your label position at runtime